# Xcode: How to change App Name for Notifications Center

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

**Scenario**

I have an app that sends notifications to the users. I have recently changed my app name in Xcode (about every way you can change it, "Bundle Name", "Product Name", you 'name' it...) and then changed it all back to the final name.

**Problem**

Now when I send a notification to the phone it doesn't show the final name change in the header section of the Notification Center. Instead, it is showing the *old* name that I changed it from.

**Picture** (circled in red - this is the part that is showing the old name)

[image]

**FYI**

Under the "Info" tab - the fields, "Bundle name" and "Bundle display name" both show the correct final name change.

And under the "Build Settings" tab - the fields, "Product Module Name" and "Product Name" both also show the correct final name change.

**Question**

Does anyone know if this is a bug or if there is a naming field I'm failing to change for this?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the device or resetting the simulator?

Comment: @EricS you saved the day! Thanks!

Comment: @Erics First time this cliche question works... Thanks!!

Comment: @EricS Thanks it worked

Comment: Delete and re-install the app worked for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rebooting the device or resetting the simulator seems to fix the issue.

*PS: Credit goes to @EricS but thought I would go ahead and make a proper answer so we don't leave the question unanswered.*

Comment: This stung me real good yesterday, thought I was going crazy and the reboot fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: What if I want to change the name of app in Notification only?

Comment: @AshutoshShukla you can't change the name of the app in the notification itself. It always uses the name of the app